# System.TimeoutException using WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

What is the best way to use I have been getting Timeout excption and below is the code I am using to FindElement.

if i use Thread.Sleep(8000) or 6000 its working as excepted but Its scattered all over my code and its hard to maintain ... is there any elegant solution for this problem?

```
    public IWebElement GetFindElement(By locator)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            return d.FindElement(locator);
        });
        return myDynamicElement;
    }
```

Error:

```
[System.TimeoutException] = {"Timed out after 20 seconds"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid thread.sleep constructions. I can recommend use Implicit waits

```
protected static void ImplicitlyWait(int timeToWait)
    {
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeToWait));
    }
```

Comment: But under the covers `ImplicitlyWait` is simply calling `Thread.sleep(200)` anyway.

Comment: `ImplicitlyWait` waits for elements to show up while `threading` just waits constant time.

Comment: @vlad: I was reading this thread and found that its good idea to introduce have a look this pls https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/webdriver/2RVnj48wWUU

Comment: You mean timers? I haven't work with them, so I'm not able to say is it good or not. Try it at practice, it might be better solution in your case.